# SQL Server group by optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, group-by

On my site I have the query below

```
SELECT 
    personagem.PersonagemId, personagem.PersonagemTitulo, personagem.PersonagemNome, 
    count(1) AS PersonagemTotal 
FROM 
    Personagens AS personagem 
JOIN 
    ConteudosPersonagens AS conteudoPersonagem ON personagem.PersonagemId = conteudoPersonagem.PersonagemId 
JOIN 
    Conteudos AS conteudo ON conteudoPersonagem.ConteudoId = conteudo.ConteudoId 
JOIN 
    Usuarios AS usuario ON conteudo.UsuarioId = usuario.UsuarioId 
WHERE 
    personagem.CategoriaId = 2595  
    AND conteudo.ConteudoTipo = 6 
    AND conteudo.ConteudoExcluido = 0 
    AND usuario.UsuarioExcluido = 0 
    AND usuario.UsuarioBanido = 0 
GROUP BY 
    personagem.PersonagemId, personagem.PersonagemTitulo, personagem.PersonagemNome 
ORDER BY 
    PersonagemTotal DESC
```

Running with `SET STATISTICS IO ON` command to know when using disk got the result

```
(6 row(s) affected)
Table 'Usuarios'. Scan count 0, logical reads 223207, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Conteudos'. Scan count 0, logical reads 480356, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ConteudosPersonagens'. Scan count 6, logical reads 394, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Personagens'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Execution Plan: [image: Execution Plan]

The tables have the count numbers

- Usuarios: 310731
- Conteudos: 1492901
- ConteudosPersonagens: 919293
- Personagens: 28281

The issue and have tried everything and can not decrease the number of reads of "conteudos "and "usuarios" tables, I tried indexed view and other resources.

Thank you

Comment: is index define on those column which are use in where clause ?count is on which table ?
also i guess you have use name column in group by which will never give correct result if properly tested.use CTE to join one by one.

Comment: Counts Usuarios: 310731, Conteudos: 1492901, ConteudosPersonagens: 919293, Personagens: 28281, yes i have to index with all the columns where

Comment: Please post the XML version of the actual execution plan.

Comment: XML Plan in http://pastebin.com/wnC5z3Vr

Comment: @TúlioHenrique - Thanks but that is the estimated plan. The actual plan has extra details that I wanted to see.

Comment: Graphic Execution plan details http://i.imgur.com/mM5bKqN.jpg, @MartinSmith how can the current plan?

Comment: @TúlioHenrique - In management studio Query menu hit the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option then run the query as normal. I wonder if the estimated number of rows from the first join (37) is a big underestimate.

Comment: @MartinSmith XML Plan with hit "Include Actual Execution Plan"   http://pastebin.com/NxzkM9VF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimated number of rows coming out of the `JOIN` between those tables is way off actual. (156,885 not 37)

[image]

as a result you are getting an underestimate of the number of rows and a quite possibly inappropriate nested loops join on the other two tables.

**First try**

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Personagens WITH FULLSCAN;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.ConteudosPersonagens WITH FULLSCAN;
```

**Second try**

OK you've done that and it raised the estimated rows by a bit (to 202) but it is still way off. You are now getting a hash join on `Conteudos` but still a nested loops on `Usuarios`. Probably the `PersonagemId` values coming from `Personagens` are much more populous than the average `PersonagemId` value is in `ConteudosPersonagens`.

You could add an explicit `HASH JOIN` hint there but one problem would be that the big under estimate of number of rows on the build input might mean spills.

So you could try this rewrite

```
SELECT personagem.PersonagemId,
       personagem.PersonagemTitulo,
       personagem.PersonagemNome,
       count(1) AS PersonagemTotal
FROM   Usuarios AS usuario
       INNER HASH JOIN Personagens AS personagem
                       INNER LOOP JOIN ConteudosPersonagens AS conteudoPersonagem
                         ON personagem.PersonagemId = conteudoPersonagem.PersonagemId
                       INNER HASH JOIN Conteudos AS conteudo
                         ON conteudoPersonagem.ConteudoId = conteudo.ConteudoId
         ON conteudo.UsuarioId = usuario.UsuarioId
WHERE  personagem.CategoriaId = 2595
       AND conteudo.ConteudoTipo = 6
       AND conteudo.ConteudoExcluido = 0
       AND usuario.UsuarioExcluido = 0
       AND usuario.UsuarioBanido = 0
GROUP  BY personagem.PersonagemId,
          personagem.PersonagemTitulo,
          personagem.PersonagemNome
ORDER  BY PersonagemTotal DESC
```

Edit: But unluckily that gives you an under-estimate too. So the memory grant may well not be sufficient for either of the two hash joins or the sort.

[image]

**Third Try**

Pre-materialise the existing poorly estimated join in a `#temp` table so SQL Server takes account of the actual number of rows for the remaining two joins.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
     PersonagemId     INT,
     PersonagemTitulo VARCHAR(100), /*Made up datatypes. Change as needed*/
     PersonagemNome   VARCHAR(100),
     ConteudoId       INT )

INSERT INTO #T
SELECT personagem.PersonagemId,
       personagem.PersonagemTitulo,
       personagem.PersonagemNome,
       conteudoPersonagem.ConteudoId
FROM   Personagens AS personagem
       JOIN ConteudosPersonagens AS conteudoPersonagem
         ON personagem.PersonagemId = conteudoPersonagem.PersonagemId
WHERE  personagem.CategoriaId = 2595

SELECT #T.PersonagemId,
       #T.PersonagemTitulo,
       #T.PersonagemNome,
       count(1) AS PersonagemTotal
FROM   #T
       JOIN Conteudos AS conteudo
         ON #T.ConteudoId = conteudo.ConteudoId
       JOIN Usuarios AS usuario
         ON conteudo.UsuarioId = usuario.UsuarioId
WHERE  conteudo.ConteudoTipo = 6
       AND conteudo.ConteudoExcluido = 0
       AND usuario.UsuarioExcluido = 0
       AND usuario.UsuarioBanido = 0
GROUP  BY #T.PersonagemId,
          #T.PersonagemTitulo,
          #T.PersonagemNome
ORDER  BY PersonagemTotal DESC
```

Comment: @TúlioHenrique - And did that fix the estimated number of rows coming out of that join or not?

Comment: After update all tables statistics Table 'Usuarios'. Scan count 0, logical reads 223311.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0.
Table 'Conteudos'. Scan count 1, logical reads 546.
Table 'ConteudosPersonagens'. Scan count 6, logical reads 394.
Table 'Personagens'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3.

Comment: @TúlioHenrique - Have you got the XML for the new actual execution plan?

Comment: The estimated number of rows coming out of the join are 202 not 33 as you said. slight improvement but not enough. You could change `JOIN Usuarios` to `INNER HASH JOIN Usuarios` or possibly use a `#temp` table to materialise the result of the first three joins and join that onto `Usuarios`.

Comment: with INNER HASH JOIN on Usuarios join    Table 'Usuarios'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3465

Comment: how to use a #temp table to materialise the result?

Comment: @TúlioHenrique Can't be bothered to write the whole thing from scractch as you didn't provide the DDL for your tables but something like `CREATE TABLE #T(...)` then `INSERT INTO #T` from the `SELECT` of all three tables except `usarios` then `SELECT ... FROM #T JOIN usarios`

Comment: with JOIN CPU time = 515 ms,  elapsed time = 1097 ms. with INNER HASH JOIN CPU time = 782 ms,  elapsed time = 651 ms.

Comment: @TúlioHenrique - Did you try the rewrite I added to my answer?

Comment: @TúlioHenrique - Plan looks OK but statistics are still off. Which might mean inadequate memory grant and hash spills. `Usuarios.UsuarioExcluido = 0 AND Usuarios.UsuarioBanido=0` estimated 77,726 vs actual 295,107 are the `STATISTICS IO` and  `STATISTICS TIME` better on the rewrite?

Comment: STATISTICS IO and STATISTICS TIME better but not ideal elapsed time = 1062 ms.

Comment: Definition of Index IDX_Usuarios_UsuarioExcluido_UsuarioBanido in http://pastebin.com/8212kxvm

Comment: @TúlioHenrique - I gave an example of what I meant with using a `#temp` table.

Comment: I was thinking of modifying the "Usuarios" table and join UsuarioExcluido and UsuarioBanido in the same field, what do you think? Would improve performance?

Comment: OUTER REFERENCES:([conteudo].[UsuarioId], [Expr1011]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH   what would that be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem the wrong number in the estimate was due to a statistics created by auto create statitics

```
CREATE STATISTICS [UsuarioBanido] ON [dbo].[Usuarios] ([UsuarioBanido]) WITH FULLSCAN

DROP STATISTICS [dbo].[Usuarios].[_WA_Sys_0000001C_7D78A4E7]
```

After this Actual Numbers of Rows been corrected

Thanks @martinsmith